# Problem with my Super key

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

[image]

When I press the Super key, my search panel does not come up and my side apps list is not showing. What can I do? I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Comment: +1 for the nice wallpaper. btw, the search panel is called *Dash* and left side icon bars is called *Launcher* officially